# Case(s) where output buffer won't flush?

Tags: c++, buffer, iostream, outputstream

I am learning about `iostream` objects and flushing the buffer. I know when output buffers are guaranteed to be flushed and how to explicitly flush the buffer. However, I have never seen a case where output buffer is *not* flushed. It seems to me that output buffer gets flushed at the end of each statement even if I don't use manipulators such as `endl`, `flush` and `ends`.

So, is there any simple example(s) where the output buffer will not ( or at least, might often not) get flushed? I feel like I need to see such a case to really understand output buffers.

Comment: Just keep in mind, that there are two levels of buffering and flushing involved: Buffering inside the upstream object, which turned of for cout by default, and Buffering of the stream in the OS.

Comment: @MikeMB `cout` has buffering turned off? Do you mean `unitbuf`? If not, can I turn it on?

Comment: [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the system.

Take the following program as an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define sleep(n) Sleep((n)*1000)
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is line 1";
    sleep(4);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "This is line 2" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

By inspecting the program, you might surmise that the program would print `This is line 1`, followed by pausing for 4 seconds, then printing `This is line 2`.

And if you compile with Visual Studio to run on Windows, you'll get that exact behavior.

On Linux and other Unix operating systems however, the program will appear to be silent for 4 seconds before printing out both lines together. The output won't reliably flush until a new line character is encountered in the output stream.

Comment: Ah so it's system dependant. That's why I have never seen such cases since I'm using Visual Studio. Thanks!

Comment: "The output won't reliably flush until a new line character is encountered in the output stream" is not *quite* correct. A newline `\n` does *not* cause a flush, but `std::endl` does since it outputs a newline followed by performing a `std::flush`. Which is what makes `std::endl` rather expensive in some cases and why one should prefer to use `\n` unless a flush is explicitly needed/wanted as well - in which case `std::endl` is the correct tool.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: You have to differentiate between std::cout and filestreams and buffering insode the iostream object and buffering in the OS / console window. By default std::cout doesn't buffer anything, but sends each input directly to the os (e.g. via `write` on linux) and usually that flushes its own buffer when receiving a newline character (or earlier). In this mode, there is almost no difference between using `\n` and `std::endl`. If you activate buffering inside the iostream object (or use a filestream) you are completely correct